# Catching errors when scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

As part of a scraping job, I am trying to catch errors and bypass them. I want to keep a `while:` loop going in spite of these errors being raised. I have this code:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# ...

except (httplib.HTTPException, IOError) as e:
    logger.exception('Ignoring exception, sleeping for 20 seconds')
    time.sleep(20)
```

But, this still throws the same socket error as before:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aa/Box Sync/Work/PythonCode/TWPh/dev.py", line 54, in <module>
    old_length = len(driver.page_source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 438, in page_source
return self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 417, in _request
resp = opener.open(request)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1200, in do_open
r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1073, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
[Finished in 24639.7s with exit code 1]
```